# how to create a 3d Euclidian point cloud and with a constant distance grid in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

can any one help me in programming a 3d Euclidian point cloud (3 dimensional array of 3d points) aligned in main axis directions (x, y z) and with a constant distance grid in c++ by using STL and c++ stream classes.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it just a 1-d array of 3d points?

You will have to decide what kind of data structure is best for your implementation.

For example, are you going to be accessing certain points more often (std::vector) or adding points (std::list) etc.   The whole list is here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

But it could be as simple as :

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} Point3d;

std::vector<Point3d> pts(1000);
```

And then use an iterator to set the initial values (randomly?)

There is some example code for the iterator here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Comment: Actually I need  to develop a grid like a  cube structure and can provide some examples.

Comment: Have a look at QuadTrees and Octrees